# Running Android emulator inside a Virtualbox Vm

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox, android, emulator

I'm trying to setup a VM with a complete android development stack (SDK, Platforms, Eclipse etc) for a Hackathon. I'm having real trouble getting the emulator to start in the VM. I realize that the emulator is essentially a VM itself inside the Vbox VM and so is going to be slow, but it just hangs at the Android splash screen and never gets any further.

Might there be something going on with the VM that is causing it to run so very slowly? Is there anything I can do to give the VM more CPU? I've tried setting the execution cap to 100% but it didn't help any.

Anyone know what might be going on here, or have any ideas about how I might speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

You can figure out what's taking so long with these commands:

```
adb kill-server
adb shell logcat
```

The emulator does take a long time to start up on -- two minutes on high-end hardware. Essentially, it's doing a full device coldstart.

Also, the emulator sometimes fails the first time you try to start a device. Just close the device and launch it again. It should work from then on.

Answer (score 0):

What OS is your VM? OS of your host? What version of Virtualbox do you use?

You need nested virtualization. Android's sdk on Linux needs Linux KVM enabled. As you said, your scenario is essentially a VM inside a VM (that's nested virtualization). Virtualbox, at least on recent versions, supports nested virtualization but supports vbox inside vbox officially. If you VM is Linux, you need KVM inside vbox. It might work, but not guaranteed.